# white space character ofr ShellExecute body in email

Tags: delphi

I want to use ShellExecute so the the user can send an email from his default email program; e.g.

```
const
  CRLF = '%0D%0A';
var
  Body: string;
begin
  Body := 'Information from my program'+CRLF+
      'that is put in the body of the email'; 
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'open', PChar('?Subject=My Subject&Body=' +  
      Body),nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I want to format the body with columns of info. How can I put in a white space? It seems that %20 will work for a single space - sometimes, but it doesn't work at the beginning of a line or for several contiguous spaces. This '      ' doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes (`Chr(34)`) inside the string:

```
Body :=  #34 + 'Information from my program' + CRLF +
      'that is put in the body of the email' + #34; 
ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'open', 
    PChar('?Subject=My Subject&Body=' + Body), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

To line up the columns, you can **try** using tab characters instead (`Chr(9)`) - as I said in my comments, I can't get `ShellExecute` to work with `mailto` on Windows 7 with Thunderbird:

```
Body :=  #34 + 'Information from my program' + CRLF +
      'that is put in the body of the email' + CRLF +
      'Col1'#9'Col2'#9'Col3' + #34;
```

(Embedding using `Stuff`#9'More stuff' is shorthand for `'Stuff' + #9 + 'More Stuff'`, BTW.

Comment: That will put the quotes also, don't know if it is undesired though..  (doublequote is %22)

Comment: @Sertac, I can't check. `mailto` won't work for me on Win7 using Thunderbird. `ShellExecute` returns `42`, which should indicate that it worked, but TB doesn't open a new email message.

Comment: What I want to do is to line up some columns: tabs don't seem to work consistently so I was thinking of putting in blank spaces. e.g.: "col1            col2             col3"

Comment: TB works for me. What I mean to line up columns is, for example: col1.........col2.........col3 but replacing the periods with spaces.

Comment: I'll edit. (Sertac gave you this answer in the comment to your original question.)

Comment: It's difficult to tell you what I'm trying to do because I can not put multiple spaces in a stackOverflow comment...so I'll use periods to represent spaces :) When I try; Body := '%22........col2%22'; what I see in my TB email program is ".col2" Only one space is preserved. Of course I'm trying to have multiple, contiguous spaces. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Of course. Use multiple contiguous replacements, one for each space: `Body='%22%22%22%22%22%22%22col2%22%22%22%22%22col3';`

Comment: I tried '%22%20%20%20%20%20Col%203%22'; but only the first space and the space after Col showed up. e.g. " Col 3"  If I removed the double quotes, than not even one space before Col 3 will show up.